# One to one lazy="no-proxy" not working in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

Recently I maintained a legacy project and it used `hibernate 3.3.2 ga`. Now I am developing a new requirement base this project, that is to implement a join query, for example there is a `foo` entity and a `bar` entity, their relationship is one to one:

```
Foo:
    Integer id; //primary key
    String orderSeq; //unique key
    //others
Bar:
    String orderSeq; //primary key refer Foo's orderSeq 
    //others

Foo.hbm.xml:
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <column name="id" />
    <generator class="identity" />
</id>
<property name="orderSeq" type="java.lang.String">
    <column name="order_seq" length="40" not-null="true" unique="true">
    </column>
</property>
<one-to-one name="bar" class="com.foo.Bar" lazy="no-proxy">
    <formula>order_seq</formula>
</one-to-one>        

Bar.hbm.xml:
<id name="orderSeq" type="java.lang.String">
    <column name="order_seq" length="40">
    </column>
</id>
<one-to-one name="foo" class="com.foo.Foo" property-ref="orderSeq" lazy="no-proxy">
</one-to-one>
```

See above configuration, I explicitly set `lazy="no-proxy"`, and from the [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone) I know that:

> lazy="no-proxy" specifies that the property should be fetched lazily when the instance variable is first accessed.

Now, when I execute below unit test:

```
@Test
public void test_query_us_order(){
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Foo a where a.orderSeq = '151207173519268'");
    query.list();
}
```

I expected only the execution of one SQL statement (`select ... from foo where foo0_.order_seq = 151207173519268`), but actually there are two more SQL statements, e.g.:

```
select ...
from
    bar bar0_ 
left outer join
    foo foo1_ 
        on bar0_.order_seq=foo1_.order_seq 
left outer join
    bar bar2_ 
        on foo1_.order_seq=bar2_.order_seq 
where
    bar0_.order_seq=?

select ... 
from
    foo foo0_ 
left outer join
    bar bar1_ 
        on foo0_.order_seq=bar1_.order_seq 
left outer join
    foo bar2_ 
        on bar1_.order_seq=bar2_.order_seq 
where
    foo0_.order_seq=?
```

Why is that so? Why doesn't the `lazy="no-proxy"` configuration work?

Comment: Do you use bytecode instrumentation for this purpose?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's your mean? The work I did is described as above,not anything else more.

Comment: In that case, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `lazy` from the documentation you quoted in your question is:

> `lazy` (optional - defaults to `proxy`): by default, single point
>   associations are proxied. `lazy="no-proxy"` specifies that the
>   property should be fetched lazily when the instance variable is first
>   accessed. **It requires build-time bytecode instrumentation.**
>   `lazy="false"` specifies that the association will always be eagerly
>   fetched.

Note the sentence that states that bytecode instrumentation is needed for `no-proxy`. This is because without it Hibernate would have no idea when you are accessing the property in your application. By modifying the generated bytecode of your application you basically inject the code that executes the lazy loading when you access the property.

If you don't utilize bytecode instrumentation, you should simply use proxies for lazy loading, meaning that you should define the association as:

```
lazy="proxy"
```

Comment: Thanks! when uses `lazy=proxy`, still need to query bar(`select  ... from bar where order_seq = ?`). And I found change `one-to-one` to `many-to-one` could get rid of additional query. e.g. `<many-to-one name="bar" class="com.foo.Bar" insert="false" update="false" >
 <column name="order_seq" length="40" />
</many-to-one>`. Now I think want to find reason of why `one-to-one` not support lazy loading ,  must to track it's source code.